# Melody notes Gouryella - Tenshi

Tags: melody

I would like to know the notes of the melody of this song

I think the notes are like this:

In 1:11:

BBBB EEEE EEEE EEEE

AAAA CCCC DDDD DDDD

GGGG C#C#C#C# EEEE F#F#F#F#

F#F#F#F# F#F#F#F# F#F#F#F# AAAA

In 1:40:

GGG AAA F#F#F# GF#E

In 1:54 (background):

GF#E GF#E GF#E GF#E

GF#D GF#D GF#D GF#D

GF#C GF#C GF#C GF#C

Is this right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! Questions about transcribing are not [on-topic](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but perhaps it can be migrated to the Music Fans stack exchange where it might be a better fit.

Comment: There are people here who enjoy answering this type of question. Try posting it in the chat room.

Comment: @AndyBonner How can I migrate the question?